# How to apply information submitted in Code Mirror?

Tags: javascript, html, css, codemirror

I am looking to build a personal code playground. Basically I am looking to make 3 Code Mirror text areas for HTML, CSS and JS, Basically I am puzzled on how to make a result box. Any help would be appreciated... Thanks :)

Just to clarify I am looking for a way (I am aware of iFrames) to submit code from 3 "CodeMirrors" and then gets applied to a result area below. I am also looking for pointers as to how todo this as I have only been coding 6 months.

Comment: an iframe like jsfiddle.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach 1 - using iframes:

It's the approach used by jsfiddle. Create 3 textareas to put your code (html, javascript, css). When the user press a button, you can send an ajax request to the server, sending the 3 texts, in order to generate a temporary page that is the composition of the various parts and returning its URL. Then create an iframe that points to it (or update the `src` of an existing one).

It's quite simple.

Approach 2 - client side:

You can append both the html, css and js in the actual page. It's quite simple, but can generate various issues with conflicting styles, ids and javascript functions/variables names (that you must manage manually).